# Access Sharepoint via python using service principal

Tags: python, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, office365api

The goal is to access files on sharepoint via python. I registered an app in AAD and granted the Sharepoint.Sites.ReadWrite.All permission. I tried using the following script to access the files on a specific Sharepoint site:

```
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

app_principal = {
    "client_id": app_id,
    "client_secret": secret_value,
}

server_url = "https://xxxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/"
site_url = server_url + "sites/xxxxxxxxxx"

context_auth = AuthenticationContext(url=site_url)
context_auth.acquire_token_for_app(
    client_id=app_principal["client_id"], client_secret=app_principal["client_secret"]
)
# returns True

ctx = ClientContext(site_url, context_auth)
web = ctx.web
ctx.load(web)
ctx.execute_query()
# return
# requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: # https://xxxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxxxxxxx/_api/Web
```

I was not able to find out where I would have to set additional permissions to be able to access the requestes site. Anyone any suggestion?

Comment: IMO, this would be an application permission. So is the admin consent granted to the client app on whose behalf you are performing the operation? And also, the token must be issued for SharePoint as the target audience I think.

Answer (score 0):

To access SharePoint files via service principal (Azure AD App Registration), you need to use **client certificate** instead of client secret.

Accessing SharePoint with client secret of Azure AD App registration is not supported

Also, provide **Sites.FullControl.All Application permission** to your App Registration and grant admin consent.

You can create a self-signed certificate and upload the certificate in your App Registration

Now, you can use the client ID, tenant ID and client certificate to access your SharePoint files

Reference: [Granting access via Azure AD App-Only | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread)

Comment: Hi, I've given the app registration of my logic app the above permissions & certification, however the service principal option isn't available for sharepoint. I saw somewhere something about having to make an http call before the action but haven't seen any significant information on this. Would you happen to know what has to be done after assigning the correct permissions?